# Use of cn1libs in cn1libs?

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible? I couldn't find anything concerning this in the documentation. When I try to refresh cn1libs (which I downloaded over the CN1 preferences) in my cn1lib project it is stated that it's not relevant for this kind of project, although I would like to write a utility library based on other cn1libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official support for dependency hierarchies in cn1libs because we don't want to create a "dependency hell". However, the extension manager does allow you to declare dependencies and you can use other cn1libs.

If you have a cn1lib you need to use you can just add it to the build classpath of the cn1lib you are currently building. In NetBeans this can be done from the GUI but can be done in other IDE's via the netbeans properties file. You can then use the other cn1lib, just make sure to include both cn1libs in the user project or you will get a dynamic link error.

See this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-nest-cn1libs-cross-dependencies.html